# OpenID implementation - PHP, Javascript, MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, sql, openid

I've started doing some research on the technologies that I will need for my website.

I'm trying to implement a really simple website with OpenID user registration. The website will store a block of text for each user.

I imagine this means that I will need a database with:

- User ID
- Open ID url
- Data

Having said that, I'm still having trouble deciding what I really need to do this. I know that I will need the following for the actual site:

- Javascript
- JQuery
- CSS

But on the back end, I'm kind of lost at the moment.

I've been looking at the OpenID-Selector, which is coded in Javascript. It seems like it's exactly what is used on this site.

Will I actually need PHP? MySQL for the data and user registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is server-side code.  If you're storing any kind of persistent data, you'll need to use a server-side language and a database.  It doesn't have to be PHP; however.  You could use C#, Java, PHP, Python, Server-Side JavaScript, Ruby, or any number of other server-side languages.

For the database, you could use MySQL, Postgres, Google App Engine's Python or Java datastore, etc.

But to answer your question, you'll need to be able to store the "key" that associates your user with your data, and you'll need to store any data related to that user.